# batch: multiple FOR parameter taken from command arguments

Tags: loops, batch-file, command-line-arguments

this is what I'm trying to do

find.bat:

```
@echo off
SET for_argument=%1
SET other_argument2=%2
SET other_argument3=%3

FOR %%A IN (%for_argument%) DO (
  echo %%A
  rem do other stuff
)
```

What I want to do is call

```
find.bat "1 2 3 4" arg2 arg3
```

and I want that `FOR` to be executed with 1 2 3 4 as separated arguments, so that the output is

```
1
2
3
4
```

But unfortunately with this code the output is

```
"1 2 3 4"
```

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Try SET for_argument=%~1, the ~ removes the quotes

Comment: @jeb I agree this is the right answer, please move it down as answer. 
@yelo3 then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET "for_argument=%~1"
```

So you get in the for argument **a b c d**, but without the quotes, this is important for the FOR loop.
A quoted string like **"a b c d"** is handled as one token, but **a b c d** is split into four tokens, allowed delims are space "," ";" or "=".